# skaffold: manifest is not being loaded when using config dependencies

Tags: skaffold

I've created a demo [git repo](https://gitlab.com/confiq/skaffold-question) with examples I'm struggling with.

I'm using `skaffold dev -p local --port-forward` command to get generated k8s configuration + to run service in minikube.

[This config works](https://gitlab.com/confiq/skaffold-question/-/blob/main/skaffold-working.yaml?ref_type=heads):

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v4beta1
kind: Config


profiles:
  - name: local
    build:  
      artifacts:
        - context: code/
          docker:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
          image: demo
    manifests:
        kustomize:
          paths:
            - code/kustomize #here it works
```

[image]

But if I change skaffold to use config dependencies [like this](https://gitlab.com/confiq/skaffold-question/-/blob/main/skaffold-not-working.yaml?ref_type=heads)

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v4beta1
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: core
requires: #this don't work
 - configs:
     - add
   path: skaffold/demo.yaml
```

The skaffold does not generate service in minikube + there is no port forwarding. The command `skaffold render` do generate the manifests.

I've [isolated the question](https://gitlab.com/confiq/skaffold-question/-/tree/main?ref_type=heads) so anyone can reproduce this.

Am I missing something? Why would skaffold not generate manifest when using config dependencies?

EDIT:

skaffold version == v2.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first scenario, where you only have one `skaffold.yaml` config file, Skaffold is able to inject a default [deployer](https://skaffold.dev/docs/deployers/), so running a command like `skaffold dev` will work as expected; it will deploy your resources.

In your second scenario, using config dependencies, it will not be able to inject a default deployer, so running `skaffold dev` won't deploy anything. This behavior explains why you can get the rendered manifests but can not get anything deployed in your cluster.

To be able to make this work you'll need to configure a deployer in your `skaffold/demo.yaml` file, it will look something like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v4beta1
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: demo

profiles:
  - name: local
    build:  
      artifacts:
        - context: code/
          docker:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
          image: demo

    manifests:
      kustomize:
        paths:
        - code/kustomize

    deploy:
      kubectl: {} # <- explicitly defining a kubectl deployer
```

And your root `skaffold.yaml` file will look like:

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v4beta1
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: core
requires:
 - configs:
     - demo
   path: skaffold/demo.yaml
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer. For more info on why it's like this:

https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/9215